# Distinguishing outgoing and incoming connections in twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'm working on a P2P application based on the Twisted framework. As such I can have both incoming as well as outgoing connections. Is there a simple way to distinguish them? Currently I just create another Factory that marks the connection as outgoing and delegates all factory calls to the original factory, but there must be a simpler way.

```
class OutgoingProtocolFactory(MyProtocolFactory):
    """
    A rather simple factory that is used to earmark connections as outgoing.
    """
    def __init__(self, parentFactory):
        self.factory = parentFactory

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        connection = MyProtocolFactory.buildProtocol(self.factory, addr)
        connection.factory = self.factory
        connection.incoming = False
        return connection

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        self.factory.clientConnectionFailed(connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        self.factory.clientConnectionLost(connector, reason)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: A socket is a socket is a socket... I.e. there is no way of distinguish between a socket created by accepting a connection or by connecting to a remote program. The only way is to keep track of it yourself, like you do now.

Comment: Yes, I know but right now I'm using another factory that does nothing more than mark it as not incoming, i.e. outgoing, and delegate everythin else back to the original factory, which seems quite stupid. It would be great if twisted would tell me whether the connection came from a connectTCP on my side or a listenTCP in which case it would be incoming.

Answer (score 0):

Each protocol instance constructed by any of the factories included in Twisted get a free `factory` attribute that refers back to the factory that created them.

By convention, accepted (server) connections have a `ServerFactory` (or subclass) instance as their factory and connected (client) connections have a `ClientFactory` (or subclass) instance.

However, if you really want your code to be completely general, you can't rely on this, and it's better to keep track of it yourself, as it sounds like you're currently doing.

In case the code you currently have for forwarding calls from one factory to another is more cumbersome than necessary, here's an example of how simple it could be:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.policies import WrappingFactory

IN, OUT = 1, 2

class YourFactory(ClientFactory):
    # Your application logic
    ...

class Incoming(WrappingFactory):
    direction = IN

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        protocol = self.wrappedFactory.buildProtocol(addr)
        protocol.direction = self.direction
        return protocol

class Outgoing(Incoming):
    direction = OUT

yourFactory = YourFactory(...)
reactor.listenTCP(0, Incoming(yourFactory))
reactor.connectTCP('example.com', 1234, Outgoing(yourFactory))
```

If that's still too complicated for you, then I don't know what to say.  I'm not clever enough to think of a simpler solution.

Comment: Since I provide those factories you're saying that the way to go is in fact to have two separate factories (one for listening and one for opening outgoing connections) and then bridge them myself (like I did by just redirecting all other calls to one of the factories). I'm sure there must be a simpler way for this.

Comment: It wasn't really clear from your question that you were using the same factory instance for incoming and outgoing connections.  I still think your current approach is the right one, though.  Perhaps you just need a simpler way of implementing that approach?  I'll edit my answer with a suggestion.